# Convert expanded blend to one simple vector shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-cs6, blend

Is it possible to convert an expanded blend to a simple lightweight vector shape, without all these inbetween paths of all `n` steps? It seems like a complicated object to work with since computer has to recalculate all the changes that are made to the inside paths.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but: Once you expand the blend (Object > Blend > Expand), the intermediate "n" objects are all independent vector shapes, and they can be edited without recalculation. They are initially grouped, but you either ungroup or just can select each one using the hollow arrow (aka direct selection tool).

[image: example blended path]